# how to convert string response to JSON response

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Here if the response is success I want to return `JSON responseStr` with status code `System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted`. But using this code I am able to return string. But I want to return Json response.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Receipt()
      {
            var response = await api.Get(string.Format(url));
            var responseStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return StatusCode((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted, responseStr);               
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogError(responseStr);
                return BadRequest(responseStr);
            }
       }
```

Comment: You can use [StatusCode(Int32, Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.statuscode?view=aspnetcore-6.0) or [Accepted(Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.accepted?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily a 202 / Accepted response wouldn't contain a body in the response.

But you can achieve this by either of the following:

return Accepted(responseStr);

Note that this will return the `responseStr` field as a string - **because it is a string**.

If you want to return it as a json object - you could deserialise it first and return the object in the same manner:

```
var asObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Type>(responseStr);
return Accepted (asObject);
```

Also, you should move the `ReadAsStringAsync` call to inside the `if (Successful) {}` block.